# Python Pandas: How to move one row to the first row of a Dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Given an existing Dataframe that is indexed.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> df
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -0.131666 -0.315019  0.306728 -0.642224 -0.294562
1  0.769310 -1.277065  0.735549 -0.900214 -1.826320
2 -1.561325 -0.155571  0.544697  0.275880 -0.451564
3  0.612561 -0.540457  2.390871 -2.699741  0.534807
4 -1.504476 -2.113726  0.785208 -1.037256 -0.292959
5  0.467429  1.327839 -1.666649  1.144189  0.322896
6 -0.306556  1.668364  0.036508  0.596452  0.066755
7 -1.689779  1.469891 -0.068087 -1.113231  0.382235
8  0.028250 -2.145618  0.555973 -0.473131 -0.638056
9  0.633408 -0.791857  0.933033  1.485575 -0.021429
>>> df.set_index("a")
                  b         c         d         e
a                                                
-0.131666 -0.315019  0.306728 -0.642224 -0.294562
 0.769310 -1.277065  0.735549 -0.900214 -1.826320
-1.561325 -0.155571  0.544697  0.275880 -0.451564
 0.612561 -0.540457  2.390871 -2.699741  0.534807
-1.504476 -2.113726  0.785208 -1.037256 -0.292959
 0.467429  1.327839 -1.666649  1.144189  0.322896
-0.306556  1.668364  0.036508  0.596452  0.066755
-1.689779  1.469891 -0.068087 -1.113231  0.382235
 0.028250 -2.145618  0.555973 -0.473131 -0.638056
 0.633408 -0.791857  0.933033  1.485575 -0.021429
```

How to move the 3rd row to the first row?

That says, expected result:

```
                  b         c         d         e
a                                                
-1.561325 -0.155571  0.544697  0.275880 -0.451564
-0.131666 -0.315019  0.306728 -0.642224 -0.294562
 0.769310 -1.277065  0.735549 -0.900214 -1.826320
 0.612561 -0.540457  2.390871 -2.699741  0.534807
-1.504476 -2.113726  0.785208 -1.037256 -0.292959
 0.467429  1.327839 -1.666649  1.144189  0.322896
-0.306556  1.668364  0.036508  0.596452  0.066755
-1.689779  1.469891 -0.068087 -1.113231  0.382235
 0.028250 -2.145618  0.555973 -0.473131 -0.638056
 0.633408 -0.791857  0.933033  1.485575 -0.021429
```

Now the original first row should become the second row.

Comment: please post a sample from your data , and expected output to make it easy to solve your problem

Comment: updated with a sample data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reindexing is probably the optimal solution for putting the rows in any new order in 1 apparent step, except it may require producing a new DataFrame which could be prohibitively large.

For example

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.read_csv('table.txt',sep='\s+')
t
Out[81]: 
  DG/VD   TYPE State Access Consist Cache sCC   Size Units   Name
0   0/0  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    one
1   1/1  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    two
2   2/2  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB  three
3   3/3  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB   four

t.index
Out[82]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')

t2 = t.reindex([2,0,1,3]) # cannot do this in place
t2
Out[93]: 
  DG/VD   TYPE State Access Consist Cache sCC   Size Units   Name
2   2/2  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB  three
0   0/0  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    one
1   1/1  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    two
3   3/3  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB   four
```

Now the index can be set back to range(4) without reindexing:

```
t2.index=range(4)
Out[102]: 
  DG/VD   TYPE State Access Consist Cache sCC   Size Units   Name
0   2/2  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB  three
1   0/0  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    one
2   1/1  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    two
3   3/3  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB   four
```

It can also be done with 'tuple switching' and row selection as a basic mechanism and without creating a new DataFrame.  For example:

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.read_csv('table.txt',sep='\s+')

t.ix[1], t.ix[2] = t.ix[2], t.ix[1]
t.ix[0], t.ix[1] = t.ix[1], t.ix[0]  
t
Out[96]: 
  DG/VD   TYPE State Access Consist Cache sCC   Size Units   Name
0   2/2  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB  three
1   0/0  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    one
2   1/1  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB    two
3   3/3  RAID1  Optl     RW      No  RWTD   -  1.818    TB   four
```

Another in place method sets the DataFrame index for the desired     ordering so that, for example, the 3rd row gets index 0, etc. and then the DataFrame is sorted in place. It's encapsulated in the following function that assumes the rows are indexed with some range(m) for positive integer m and the DataFrame is simply indexed (no MultiIndex) as in the example provided in the question.

```
def putfirst(n,df):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        print 'error: 1st arg must be an int'
        return
    if n < 1:
        print 'error: 1st arg must be an int > 0'
        return
    if n == 1:
       print 'nothing to do when first arg == 1'
       return
    if n > len(df):
       print 'error: n exceeds the number of rows in the DataFrame'
       return
    df.index = range(1,n) + [0] + range(n,df.index[-1]+1)
    df.sort(inplace=True)
```

The arguments of putfirst are n, which is the ordinal position of the row to relocate to the first row position, so that if the 3rd row is to be so relocated then n = 3; and df is the DataFrame containing the row to be relocated.

Here is a demo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df.set_index("a") # ineffective without assignment or inplace=True
Out[182]: 
                  b         c         d         e
a                                                
 1.394072 -1.076742 -0.192466 -0.871188  0.420852
-1.211411 -0.258867 -0.581647 -1.260421  0.464575
-1.070241  0.804223 -0.156736  2.010390 -0.887104
-0.977936 -0.267217  0.483338 -0.400333  0.449880
 0.399594 -0.151575 -2.557934  0.160807  0.076525
-0.297204 -1.294274 -0.885180 -0.187497 -0.493560
-0.115413 -0.350745  0.044697 -0.897756  0.890874
-1.151185 -2.612303  1.141250 -0.867136  0.383583
-0.437030  0.347489 -1.230179  0.571078  0.060061
-0.225524  1.349726  1.350300 -0.386653  0.865990

df
Out[183]: 
          a         b         c         d         e
0  1.394072 -1.076742 -0.192466 -0.871188  0.420852
1 -1.211411 -0.258867 -0.581647 -1.260421  0.464575
2 -1.070241  0.804223 -0.156736  2.010390 -0.887104
3 -0.977936 -0.267217  0.483338 -0.400333  0.449880
4  0.399594 -0.151575 -2.557934  0.160807  0.076525
5 -0.297204 -1.294274 -0.885180 -0.187497 -0.493560
6 -0.115413 -0.350745  0.044697 -0.897756  0.890874
7 -1.151185 -2.612303  1.141250 -0.867136  0.383583
8 -0.437030  0.347489 -1.230179  0.571078  0.060061
9 -0.225524  1.349726  1.350300 -0.386653  0.865990

df.index
Out[184]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')

putfirst(3,df)
df
Out[186]: 
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -1.070241  0.804223 -0.156736  2.010390 -0.887104
1  1.394072 -1.076742 -0.192466 -0.871188  0.420852
2 -1.211411 -0.258867 -0.581647 -1.260421  0.464575
3 -0.977936 -0.267217  0.483338 -0.400333  0.449880
4  0.399594 -0.151575 -2.557934  0.160807  0.076525
5 -0.297204 -1.294274 -0.885180 -0.187497 -0.493560
6 -0.115413 -0.350745  0.044697 -0.897756  0.890874
7 -1.151185 -2.612303  1.141250 -0.867136  0.383583
8 -0.437030  0.347489 -1.230179  0.571078  0.060061
9 -0.225524  1.349726  1.350300 -0.386653  0.865990
```

Comment: here you've swapped the first and third rows , this is not the expected output

Comment: @Fiabetto: thanks for the information. combining row selection with concat is good and I will keep it in my toolchest

Comment: @NaderHisham: Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer to solve the question with reindexing and tuple switching.

Comment: @TrisNefzger I find this does not do swap but make a duplicate of the t.ix[2]: t.ix[1], t.ix[2] = t.ix[2], t.ix[1]. It seems that the two assignment happened in order from left to right, not in parallel.

Comment: @Rex: That's interesting.  How do you know?  Why does it matter? I wonder if that's always the case regardless of the objects being swapped or if Panda Streams as DataFrame columns are a special case and if so why?  I'll do some research on my end.  In any case just relabling the index and sorting the DataFrame  is more general purpose, but I wonder what is the overhead for the sorting of a large DataFrame" --  I think its really just the index that gets sorted and the rows go along for the ride.

Answer (score 15):

To move the third row to the first, you can create an index moving the target row to the first element.  I use a conditional list comprehension to join by lists.

Then, just use `iloc` to select the desired index rows.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df
          a         b         c
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863

target_row = 2
# Move target row to first element of list.
idx = [target_row] + [i for i in range(len(df)) if i != target_row]

>>> df.iloc[idx]
          a         b         c
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

if desired, you can also reset your index.

```
>>> df.iloc[idx].reset_index(drop=True)
          a         b         c
0  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
1  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
2  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

Alternatively, you can just reindex the list using `idx`:

```
>>> df.reindex(idx)
          a         b         c
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

Comment: It's cool to have idx first, and then use df.iloc[idx] for the new dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

This is not elegant, but works so far:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> df
      a         b         c         d         e
0  1.124763 -0.416770  1.347839 -0.944334  0.738686
1 -0.348112  0.786822 -1.161970 -1.645065 -0.075205
2  0.549966  0.357076 -0.880669 -0.187731 -0.221997
3  0.311057 -0.126432 -1.187644  2.151804  0.791835
4 -0.310849  0.753750 -1.087447  0.095884  1.449832
5 -0.272344  0.278788 -0.724369 -0.568442  0.164909
6  0.942927 -0.273203  0.203322  1.099572 -0.505160
7  0.526321  1.665012  0.915676 -1.174497 -2.270662
8 -0.959773  0.921732  1.396364 -1.383112  0.603030
9 -2.802902 -0.572469 -1.599550 -1.305605  0.578198
>>> row = df.ix[0].copy()
>>> row
a    1.124763
b   -0.416770
c    1.347839
d   -0.944334
e    0.738686
Name: 0, dtype: float64
>>> df.ix[0]=df.ix[2]
>>> df.ix[2]=row
>>> df
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.549966  0.357076 -0.880669 -0.187731 -0.221997
1 -0.348112  0.786822 -1.161970 -1.645065 -0.075205
2  1.124763 -0.416770  1.347839 -0.944334  0.738686
3  0.311057 -0.126432 -1.187644  2.151804  0.791835
4 -0.310849  0.753750 -1.087447  0.095884  1.449832
5 -0.272344  0.278788 -0.724369 -0.568442  0.164909
6  0.942927 -0.273203  0.203322  1.099572 -0.505160
7  0.526321  1.665012  0.915676 -1.174497 -2.270662
8 -0.959773  0.921732  1.396364 -1.383112  0.603030
9 -2.802902 -0.572469 -1.599550 -1.305605  0.578198
>>> df.set_index('a')
                  b         c         d         e
a                                                
 0.549966  0.357076 -0.880669 -0.187731 -0.221997
-0.348112  0.786822 -1.161970 -1.645065 -0.075205
 1.124763 -0.416770  1.347839 -0.944334  0.738686
 0.311057 -0.126432 -1.187644  2.151804  0.791835
-0.310849  0.753750 -1.087447  0.095884  1.449832
-0.272344  0.278788 -0.724369 -0.568442  0.164909
 0.942927 -0.273203  0.203322  1.099572 -0.505160
 0.526321  1.665012  0.915676 -1.174497 -2.270662
-0.959773  0.921732  1.396364 -1.383112  0.603030
-2.802902 -0.572469 -1.599550 -1.305605  0.578198
```

If that's what you want...

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

you can simply do the following

```
df.reindex([2, 0 ,1] + range(3, len(df)))
```

or you can do the following

```
pd.concat([ df.reindex([2, 0, 1]) , df.iloc[3:]])

# this line rearrange the first 3 rows
df.reindex([2, 0, 1])

# slice data from third row 
df.iloc[3:]

# concatenate both results together
pd.concat([ df.reindex([2, 0 ,1]), df.iloc[3:]])
```