# Having trouble moving a row to the top of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've got 280 CSV files and for each of them I need to create a row that contains the sum of all its numeric values.This is simple but my problem is that the sumation needs to be in the first row.

I've been using this code to create the summation row in the file

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path,sep=";",header=2, engine="python")

df.[Soma] = df.sum(numeric_only="boolean")
```

Now I need to move the summation to the first row. I'm obviously not the first one with this problem, but i'm having trouble when trying to make it work! My csv file is quite large so I can't simply reorder the rows in the dataframe manually.

There is one proposed solution here which looks good: 
[Python Pandas: How to move one row to the first row of a Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547440/python-pandas-how-to-move-one-row-to-the-first-row-of-a-dataframe)

To make it possible to post the dataframe here i excluded most of the rows and columns in the CSV file. This is how it looks right now(still haven't managed to make it work):

```
       DATA_BASE   UF      COD            MUN        CNPJ

0      199407.0   AC   1030.0    MANCIO LIMA   4064077.0   
1      199407.0   AC   5184.0  MANOEL URBANO   4064077.0   
2      199407.0   AC   9465.0   ASSIS BRASIL   4064077.0   
3      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4064077.0   
4      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4902979.0   
5      199407.0   AC  18690.0         XAPURI         0.0   
soma  1196442.0  NaN  66325.0            NaN  21159287.0
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so thanks to @piRSquared I think  i have a good written method function:

```
def putfirst(df, i):
    return df.iloc[(np.arange(len(df)) != i).argsort()]

putfirst(df,df.index.get_loc('soma'))
```

But for whatever reason nothing is happening to the data frame. I don't get any errors so I think Python is simply not calling the function, but I cannot figure out why.
The indentation looks right to me:

[image: How it looks to me]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sample data frame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np. arange(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
df

    A   B   C   D
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
```

---

#### Use combination of `iloc` and `argsort`

I'll be depending on two things

1. Sorting on a boolean array puts `False` first, so I am sorting when a simple sequenced array is **not equal** to the target row.
2. Sorting is stable so all `True` values will stay in same relative order.
3. `argsort` returns the array I need to slice with `iloc`.

---

```
def putfirst(df, i):
    return df.iloc[(np.arange(len(df)) != i).argsort()]
```

---

```
putfirst(df, 3)

    A   B   C   D
3  12  13  14  15
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
```

---

```
putfirst(df, 2)

    A   B   C   D
2   8   9  10  11
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
3  12  13  14  15
```

---

#### `head` and `tail` for swapping last row

```
df.tail(1).append(df.head(-1))

    A   B   C   D
3  12  13  14  15
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
```

---

**With Your Sample**

```
putfirst(df, 6)

      DATA_BASE   UF      COD            MUN        CNPJ
soma  1196442.0  NaN  66325.0            NaN  21159287.0
0      199407.0   AC   1030.0    MANCIO LIMA   4064077.0
1      199407.0   AC   5184.0  MANOEL URBANO   4064077.0
2      199407.0   AC   9465.0   ASSIS BRASIL   4064077.0
3      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4064077.0
4      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4902979.0
5      199407.0   AC  18690.0         XAPURI         0.0
```

Or

```
putfirst(df, len(df) - 1)

      DATA_BASE   UF      COD            MUN        CNPJ
soma  1196442.0  NaN  66325.0            NaN  21159287.0
0      199407.0   AC   1030.0    MANCIO LIMA   4064077.0
1      199407.0   AC   5184.0  MANOEL URBANO   4064077.0
2      199407.0   AC   9465.0   ASSIS BRASIL   4064077.0
3      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4064077.0
4      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4902979.0
5      199407.0   AC  18690.0         XAPURI         0.0
```

Or

```
putfirst(df, df.index.get_loc('soma'))

      DATA_BASE   UF      COD            MUN        CNPJ
soma  1196442.0  NaN  66325.0            NaN  21159287.0
0      199407.0   AC   1030.0    MANCIO LIMA   4064077.0
1      199407.0   AC   5184.0  MANOEL URBANO   4064077.0
2      199407.0   AC   9465.0   ASSIS BRASIL   4064077.0
3      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4064077.0
4      199407.0   AC  15978.0          FEIJO   4902979.0
5      199407.0   AC  18690.0         XAPURI         0.0
```

Comment: This looks like a good idea, but it's not working with my code! While i don't get any errors the rows don't get moved at all. I should copy              
 def putfirst(df, i):
    return df.iloc[(np.arange(len(df)) != i).argsort()]                                       
with 
putfirst(df,10875)   right?

Comment: This is the reason we ask people to provide a [mcve].  It helps resolve ambiguity.  There is some nuance in your data set that you have not communicated and therefore I'm not aware of.  If you provide a working example of your data and what you want it to look like, I can be far more helpful.

Comment: Sorry I was still editing my first reply! I edited my post with a screenshot of the initial CSV file and my output. Take a look! if it helps you understand! And thank you for the patience @piRSquared

Comment: Pictures are not good.  If you think about it, the only way for me to use it is to transcribe it.  How long do you think that will take me?  It will take a while.  It is always best if you can provide the means to produce the example data.  The most common approach is to paste the text into your question directly.  You can format it nicely.  But even if you can't, somebody else can edit your post and format it.  It being in the post makes it so much easier to help you.

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the help. I've edited a post with a sample of the dataframe.Can you take a look? @piRSquared

Comment: @PedroSalgado I've included demonstrations with your data.

Comment: Looks perfect but it's still not working for me, can you check my update on the initial post? @piRSquared

Comment: @PedroSalgado reassign the results back to df.